# Configure number of received values that toReturnWith reports

Tags: jestjs

When `expect(someMock).toReturnWith(someValue)` fails, it shows the expected value, and the received values, but it appears to only show 3 values even when the mock was called more than 3 times:

```js
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toReturnWith(expected)

Expected: "400"
Received
       1: "-40"
       2: "0"
       3: "40"

Number of returns: 11
```

Is there a way to configure how many received values are shown?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to configure this, but you can get all values that have been passed to a mock function using `yourMockFunction.mock.calls`. For example:

```
test("drink returns twice", () => {
  const drink = jest.fn(x => x);

  drink("beer");
  drink("wine");
  drink("water");
  drink("orange juice");

  console.log(drink.mock.calls); // [ [ 'beer' ], [ 'wine' ], [ 'water' ], [ 'orange juice' ] ]
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-property